# normalization of database structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I was reading the concept of normalization of database structure. I got confused with the following situation in my project.

1. I have two tables "`TableA`" and `TableB`
2. Both tables are independent of each other and have no realtionship at all
3. They represent completely different data
4. Both the tables will have different parameters. However `Parameter` itself as an object has same properties.

So my concern is should I have single `Parameter` table which is serving `TableA` and `TableB` both

Or

I should have separate `Parameter` Table for both `Table A` and `Table B`

Structure look likes this

**Case I:**

```
TableA
ID
Name
Description

TableB
ID
Name
SomeFlag

Parameter
ID
TableA_ID
TableB_ID
Name 
Description
Type
```

**Case II**

```
TableA
ID
Name
Description

Parameter_A
ID
TableA_ID
Name 
Description
Type

TableB
ID
Name
SomeFlag

Parameter_B
ID
TableB_ID
Name 
Description
Type
```

I personally prefer Case I, as it does make sense to create another table representing same type of data.

As per normalization's concept we should have a table that represents only one thing. So i guess i should have only one parameter table. But what if that table mean something completely different when viewed from TableA and different when viewed from TableB?

Comment: The first Case is bad design. What happens when you add `Table C` or `Table D`. You have to `ALTER TABLE` your params table. Case II satisfies your requirements, allows you to scale with quicker queries, keeps you away from storing tables as fields in your params table, and doesn't fall into the EAV anti-pattern. If you want to add some extra normalization into Case II, then take your `Name, Description, and Type` and stick them into their own table, using your existing `parameter_N` table just for the relationship between `Table_N` and it's params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use case one but with some changes.  The parameter entity does hold one thing, parameters for a table.  An instance of a parameter entry should relate to only one table (based on your analysis that they are not related).

```
Parameter
----------
PK Param_ID 
FK Main_Table_ID 
Main_Table_name (A or B)
param_Name 
param_Description
param_Type
```

Comment: why you consider having Table_ID + Table_Name combination better than having two columns of Table_ID as i have?

Comment: This causes (params * Table_N) records in the parameters table. This is pretty much Case II, but combining the two param tables into a single table. You still dupe your params records, but you do it one spot. If your DB support partitioning and you use this, then partition by Table_Name (which is really getting close to Case II). If your DB doesn't support partitioning, then consider just going with Case II instead.

Comment: @JNevill thanks for the explaination...so i guess i can modify the parameter table as suggested by Gary as a compromise between Case I and II. However best practice would be to have separate parameter Tables?

Comment: @Ankit: The design can then handle holding parameters for more than 2 tables without having to change the table and thus queries and code surrounding it.

Comment: I wouldn't want to say "Best practice" since each DB schema is unique (except in really routine stuff like Blogs or Order management). It's dependant on your RDBMS's architecture, your need for fast reads or fast writes, stability, scale, etc.. It just depends. This is a nice option since if you add a Table_C you don't have to make a new params table (or relationship to the params table) you just start slinging records into your single param table and you're golden.

Comment: This is a good place to say there is sometimes a gray area between proper data modeling and designing for efficient queries and code maintenance.  Take all that into account when designing.

Comment: I cringe when I see a column named "tableID".  It smacks of a schema design that you will regret.

Comment: Agreed! It should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

If it makes logical sense for a Parameter to have **both** Table A **and** Table B in the same instance (not an either/or), then Case I is better.

In Relational Theory, every table is a type. Even if they may have common data, types are based around their usage. And though it's a little more complicated, Case II is more normalized.

There is another possibiltiy, that hasn't been mentioned, I'll call it Case III.

```
TableA
ID
Name
Description
PropertyID

TableB
ID
Name
SomeFlag
PropertyID

Parameter
ID
Name 
Description
Type
```

If the Properties will always be common among both tables, this is probably going to be the best solution.

Comment: Lets take an example.. i have a table Category..for which Parameter table act as Questions....each category can have many questions....... other table is product....for product, parameter acts as products properties.......so each product can have many properties.... now which case is better?

Comment: In this case having separate QuestionsProperties and  ProductsProperties is probably best.
In the future, you may have to add columns to ProductsProperties that just wouldn't make sense in QuestionsProperties.

Comment: It also just occured to me that if there are truly common properties that they will share, they can be subtypes of a larger table and the Questions and Products will have thier own FK into the common Properties table.